# On Lyapunov's method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

I been reading the standard proof of Lyapunov's method (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_stability)

for example page $7$ here,

https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-241j-dynamic-systems-and-control-spring-2011/readings/MIT6_241JS11_chap13.pdf

I can't see why and where we really need that the function $V(x)\ \ge0$. Could someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 1):

Some geometric ideas about Lyapunov's method.

Given a dynamical system

$$
\dot x = f(x,t)
$$

Suppose that $V(0) = 0$ and $V(x) > 0 $ for $x \ne 0$ then there exist a closed level curve/surface around $x=0$ indexed by a suitable $\epsilon > 0$ or $V(x) = \epsilon$

Now $\dot V(x) = \nabla V(x)\dot x = \nabla V(x)f(x,t) \le 0$

tell us that the directional derivative for $V(x)$ in the dynamic system's direction is negative. This show us that the dynamic system's path is entering the level curve/surface associated to $V(x) = \epsilon$

So it is essential that around $x=0$ assumed as the equilibrium point, the existence of a closed curve/surface. This is guaranteed by $V(x) = \epsilon > 0$

I hope this helps.

Comment: But why does the epislon have to be positive? woult we reach a negative number also?

Comment: ah, we might not need to enter a negative level curve. Since the origin is positive. Right?

Comment: $V(x) > 0$ for $x \ne 0$ as previously stated. Then there exists $\epsilon > 0$

Comment: yes but why does this nesseseraly need to be postive, thats my question. Why cant we have a negative level surface doing the job.

Comment: @oxire Because it follows from the assumptions that the level set of $V$ corresponding to a negative value is empty.

Comment: yes  I know, but why do we need this assumption why cant we relax it?

Comment: If your Lyapunov function has some physical meaning you are free to assume that it takes some negative value (having physical interpretation) at zero.  Similarly you can take any equilibrium instead of the origin.  But in general $V(0)$ is assumed to be zero just to streamline the presentation.

Comment: @user539887 but must we have that the value dosnt go below the value at the origin? I dont think it matters.

Comment: If you are looking for a sufficient condition for asymptotic/Lyapunov stability, then yes, it does matter:  the values of $V(x)$ for $x \ne 0$ in some neighborhood of the origin must be strictly larger than $V(0)$.